# Making a Extracting/Compiling program in Visual C++ 2010 but have errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-construction, extractor

I am building a .SM2 and .RM2 extractor/compiler for a game but I am having trouble with the code. I am not experienced in C++ at all and the code is source code given by the original creator. Even his original file that wasnt edited by me had errors but he still made the program. Can someone please help me with the errors?

> Errors:
>
> Error1: error C2664: 'CreateDirectoryW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [25]' to 'LPCWSTR'
>
> Error2: error C2664: 'CreateDirectoryW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'LPCWSTR'(X3)
>
> Error4: error C2664: 'FindFirstFileW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char [256]' to'LPCWSTR'
>
> Error5: error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'WCHAR [260]' to 'char*'

Here is my code that apparently have the errors:

```
CreateDirectory(".\\TESTFOLDER\\TESTFOLD2ER", NULL);   (This is for Error 1)

CreateDirectory(string, NULL);
break;                          (This is for Error2)


if ((hdl = FindFirstFile(asteriskpath, &data)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    return;       (For Error3)

char* filename = data.cFileName;
char current_dir[256];       (For Error4)
```

Please help,
Thanks,
   Cameron
       Sawaya

Comment: It sounds like your project is set to unicode when the code you were given expects the project to be set to multi-byte character set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1**: set your project character setting to `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`:

> Configure Properties > General > Project Defaults > Character Set > Use Multi-Byte Character Set

---

**Method 2**:

- For Error 1/2/4:

  You should convert `char[]` to `wchar_t[]` first before passing to `CreateDirectory()` (For your Error 1, similar for other errors 2 and 4) as they are using different character encoding types. Try `swprintf` with the `%hs` flag.

  Example:

  ```
  wchar_t  ws[100];
  swprintf(ws, 100, L"%hs", ".\TESTFOLDER\TESTFOLD2ER");
  ```
- For Error 5:

  You can use the `wcstombs` function to convert `wchar_t[]` to `char[]`, reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs).

---

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. IVE BEEN TRYING AND GETTING SO ANGRY TRYING TO FIX THOSE ERRORS. THANK YOU SO MUCH.